# Automatic pupil distances using a mobile app

Tags: software, app

In reference to the patent: [US9091867](https://www.google.com/patents/US9091867)

Is this method available to automatically get the pupil distances using an app on a mobile device?

Comment: Could you provide more details to clarify your question?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. Like vallismortis said, some more details on what you'd like us to answer would help. If you can, please [edit] your question to help with that. It might be a good idea to check out our [help/on-topic] as well to see what we're best at helping with.